# NODE.js & socket.io: how to check whether user is online/offline?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js

I am making a chat application and I want to add an option to check whether user is online or offline.

Assume I have an array of names (it's a current replacement for a future database), which is represented as 'all the users in chat ever existed'.

```
var users = {user1,user2,user3,...usern};
```

And also, assume I have some kind of html form for entering your username

```
<p>Enter your username</p>
<p id="nickError"></p>
<form id="setNick">
    <input size="35" id="nickname" maxlength="25"></input>
    <button>Chat!</button>
</form>
```

I have logic and code to check whether the name from input area is in users array. Also, I have a basic chat in which you can talk globally or in private.

Part of my server.js:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('new user',function(data,callback){
        if (data in users)
        {
        callback(false);
        } else{
            callback(true);
            socket.nickname = data;
            users[socket.nickname] = socket; 
            updateNicknames();
            io.emit('user joined', data);
        }
    });

};
```

I wanted to make a function, named `updateNicknames()`, which will update the status of the user, so if a person with nickname which is in my user 'database' is connected, his status should be online, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove user from array on the `disconnect` event.

Comment: But I still want all the users to be in array. For example, if the user is online, his name will be bold,and if not, his text-color will be painted red.
Also, I wanted to add an option if user is away - if he is connected,but didn't write/respond to a message for a certain amount of time.

Comment: asked the same question about 2 days ago [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156500/mongoose-query-for-connected-friends/33165801#33165801)